# Laravel Scheduler: how to run task on weekdays only?

Tags: php, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am writing Laravel scheduler task and want to run it once a day every weekday (From Monday to Friday).

I see that [Task Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling) has `->weekdays()` option, that presumably does precisely what I want.
But I wasn't able to find a confirmation or description of this option that says it will run from Monday to Friday and not, say, from Monday to Saturday.

Also I would like to run the task at specific time. I see there is a `->dailyAt('13:00');` method. I'd like to know the best solution to run task at weekdaysAt.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I use Laravel 5.2, in case that matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this is a confirmation, the source code of the `weekdays()` method:

```
public function weekdays()
{
    return $this->spliceIntoPosition(5, '1-5');
}
```

You can find it here: `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Event.php`

Right after `weekdays()` you will see `mondays()` method, which shows that Laravel counts mondays as "day 1":

```
public function mondays()
{
        return $this->days(1);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use this code for the second part of the question

```
->weekdays()->at('time you want')
```

Based on the Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scheduling).

Comment: This is an old question but this is the only answer you should use. 110%